# Why is stringstream ss(s) different from ss << s?

Tags: c++, string, constructor, stringstream, bidirectional

When I try to use stringstream like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::string s = "Hello World Test";
    std::stringstream ss(s);

    std::string a, b;
    ss >> a >> b;
    std::cout << a << ' ' << b << std::endl; // Hello World

    ss << " Why Not";
    ss >> a >> b;
    std::cout << a << ' ' << b << std::endl; // Still Hello World

    std::string c, d;
    std::stringstream tt;
    tt << s;

    tt >> c >> d;
    std::cout << c << ' ' << d << std::endl; // Hello World

    tt << " Now Yes";
    tt >> c >> d;  // print Now Yes
    std::cout << c << ' ' << d << std::endl; // Test Now
}
```

Does any one know why stringsteam construct behaves differently?

I expect stringstream can go in and out freely. But it seems not. If used in one direction, I dont any problem.

Comment: Nope https://godbolt.org/z/en4c1b7b1

Comment: @273K: that shows the second line of output being `Test World` when it should be `Test Why`

Comment: Not Still Hello World

Comment: @273K That's perhaps worth an answer after all.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I can't find a manual reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a stringstream from a string like this, the default mode is `in|out` -- meaning input or output is allowed, BUT all the pointers default to pointing at the beginning of the buffer.  So when you write into the stringstream with `<<` it overwrites the string there, and your reads at the end will just run off the end.

If you instead do

```
std::stringstream ss(s, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::ate);
```

(adding the 'at the end' flag) it will work more like you expect, starting the pptr at the end of the initial string.

Why this is not the default is a bit of a mystery (probably just a mistake in the earliest implementations that got codified in the standard as noone wanted to break backward compatibility with this misfeature).

Comment: Thank you Chris. Now I learned the istream pointer(tellg, seekg) and ostream pointer (tellp, seekp) are separated. Actually this is my first time to know tellg and seekg function. Why has the standard commitee chosen tellg and seekg as function names? I guess it is because letter 'g' looks opposite to letter 'p'. If that is the case, why haven't we chosen tellq and seekq, which looks better to me at least?

Comment: `g` and `p` stand for 'get' and 'put' -- where you "get" data from in the buffer and where you "put" data to in the buffer.

Comment: Oh, thank you for such detail explanation.